# Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'pin='

Tags: database, ms-access

I am trying to pass database value into a another from using visual studio windows form. How do I access the data outside the while loop? and save to a string and pass that value into form2. I keep getting this error when passing to form2: Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'pin='

my code for form1:

```
namespace ATM
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String conn_string = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data     Source=C:\\Users\\Dro\\Desktop\\ATM\\Database11.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbConnection conn = null;
        public int pinnumber = 3300;
        public string dbpin;
        public string oppin;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            runQuery();

            //checks PIN is entered or not 
            if (textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "----";
            }
            else if (dbpin == textBox2.Text)//checks whether pin is correct and then shows the form 2(menu)
            {
                Form2 menu = new Form2();
                menu.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {

                textBox1.Text = "The PIN is Incorrect! Try Again!";


            }
        }



        private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (textBox2.Text == "----")
            {
                textBox2.Clear();
                textBox1.Clear();
            }


            if (textBox2.Text.Length < 4)
            {
                Button button = (Button)sender;
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + button.Text;
                textBox2.PasswordChar = '*';

             }


        }





        private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Clear();

        }
        private void runQuery()
        {

             conn = new OleDbConnection(conn_string);
             MessageBox.Show("successfully connected");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM atmDB where pin="+textBox2.Text;
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                dbpin = dr["PIN"].ToString();

            }
            MessageBox.Show(dbpin);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove all of the non-relevant code. We really don't need all of those empty event handlers. Post only the code that is actually applicable to the problem you're having, so we don't have to sift through all of the other noise. After you do that, search for *parameterized queries* and get rid of the SQL concatenation (`pin=" + textBox2.Text`), and your problem will go away.

Comment: when SQL compares strings in a where a static string needs to be enclosed in single quotes.  so you want this: cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM atmDB where pin= '"+ textBox2.Text + "'";

Comment: You need to re-tag this.  Is this VB?  C#?  C++?  No strictly Access developer is going to have an answer for you.